# gnuplot, problem with margins in spiderplot

Tags: gnuplot, margins

I am trying to create a spider plot using data from several files. Everything is in order (axes, values etc) with the exception of the margins and plot title position.

The script in use and the resulting image follo:

```
set title "Optimal solutions for the subcritical conventional cycle"

set termopt enhanced 
set encoding utf8
set terminal windows
set size ratio -1

set spiderplot
#set grid spiderplot

set style spiderplot fs transparent solid 0.2 border lw 1.5 pt 7 ps 1.5

set paxis 1 range[100:275]
set paxis 2 range[0:10]
set paxis 3 range[0:25]
set paxis 4 range[0:25]

set paxis 1 label "T_{evap} [^{o}C]"
set paxis 2 label "     ΔT_{super} [^{o}C]"
set paxis 3 label "ΔT_{pp,evap} [^{o}C]"
set paxis 4 label "ΔT_{pp,cond} [^{o}C]     "

set paxis 1 tics 100,25,275
set paxis 2 tics 0,1,10
set paxis 3 tics 0,5,25
set paxis 4 tics 0,5,25

plot \
     keyentry with spiderplot lc "#E74C3C" lw 1.5 title "R124",\
     for [i=1:4] "optsub_conv_optimal_solution_R124.txt" using i notitle lw 1.5 lc "#E74C3C",\
     newspiderplot,\
     keyentry with spiderplot lc "#F39C12" lw 1.5 title "Isobutane",\
     for [i=1:4] "optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Isobutane.txt" using i notitle lw 1.5 lc "#F39C12",\
     newspiderplot,\
     keyentry with spiderplot lc "#2ECC71" lw 1.5 title "R245fa",\
     for [i=1:4] "optsub_conv_optimal_solution_R245fa.txt" using i notitle lw 1.5 lc "#2ECC71",\
     newspiderplot,\
     keyentry with spiderplot lc "#3498DB" lw 1.5 title "Isopentane",\
     for [i=1:4] "optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Isopentane.txt" using i notitle lw 1.5 lc "#3498DB",\
     newspiderplot,\
     keyentry with spiderplot lc "#9B59B6" lw 1.5 title "Cyclopentane",\
     for [i=1:4] "optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Cyclopentane.txt" using i notitle lw 1.5 lc "#9B59B6"
```

[spiderplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDU4b.png)

Evidently, the plot appears with too much white space on the sides. Additionally the title appears right on top of an axis label, while another axis label lies outside the plot.
The typical margin commands (tmargin,bmargin,lmargin,rmargin) do not appear to work.
Any ideas?

These are the data files:
optsub_conv_optimal_solution_R124.txt

```
#(1) Tevap [oC] (2) DTsuper [oC] (3) DTppevap [oC] (4) DTppcond [oC] (5) nth [-] (6) nex [-] (7) wnet [kJ/kg] (8) mwf [kg/s] (9) nthchp [-] (10) nelchp [-] (11) nchp [-] (12) PHR [-] (13) PESR [-] (14) Toout [oC] (15) mo [kg/s] (16) Twoout [oC] (17) mw [kg/s] (18) Aevap [m^2] (19) Acond [m^2]
     109.741738         9.911802         13.686376         10.490225    0.079108    0.777738     11901.389154       4.667989       0.874848        0.067637      0.942485     0.077313      0.150392       73.898046       1.431867        53.509008       4.618337         2.153230         2.338824
```

optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Isobutane.txt

```
#(1) Tevap [oC] (2) DTsuper [oC] (3) DTppevap [oC] (4) DTppcond [oC] (5) nth [-] (6) nex [-] (7) wnet [kJ/kg] (8) mwf [kg/s] (9) nthchp [-] (10) nelchp [-] (11) nchp [-] (12) PHR [-] (13) PESR [-] (14) Toout [oC] (15) mo [kg/s] (16) Twoout [oC] (17) mw [kg/s] (18) Aevap [m^2] (19) Acond [m^2]
     129.026974         9.784578         10.589184          7.690567    0.097319    0.802556     36554.377923       1.519806       0.857547        0.083208      0.940755     0.097030      0.170107       71.949670       1.155533        59.034857       3.158823         2.010785         2.219941
```

optsub_conv_optimal_solution_R245fa.txt

```
#(1) Tevap [oC] (2) DTsuper [oC] (3) DTppevap [oC] (4) DTppcond [oC] (5) nth [-] (6) nex [-] (7) wnet [kJ/kg] (8) mwf [kg/s] (9) nthchp [-] (10) nelchp [-] (11) nchp [-] (12) PHR [-] (13) PESR [-] (14) Toout [oC] (15) mo [kg/s] (16) Twoout [oC] (17) mw [kg/s] (18) Aevap [m^2] (19) Acond [m^2]
     148.519152         9.253894         16.742495          5.918559    0.117315    0.819801     26564.547418       2.091342       0.838550        0.100305      0.938855     0.119617      0.190727       76.298702       0.974274        60.864612       2.447578         1.892059         2.023517
```

optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Isopentane.txt

```
#(1) Tevap [oC] (2) DTsuper [oC] (3) DTppevap [oC] (4) DTppcond [oC] (5) nth [-] (6) nex [-] (7) wnet [kJ/kg] (8) mwf [kg/s] (9) nthchp [-] (10) nelchp [-] (11) nchp [-] (12) PHR [-] (13) PESR [-] (14) Toout [oC] (15) mo [kg/s] (16) Twoout [oC] (17) mw [kg/s] (18) Aevap [m^2] (19) Acond [m^2]
     178.491873         8.061367         17.725536          5.478487    0.136583    0.843387     68534.805634       0.810618       0.820246        0.116779      0.937025     0.142370      0.209648       78.618217       0.844249        67.467127       1.770176         1.957984         1.699375
```

optsub_conv_optimal_solution_Cyclopentane.txt

```
#(1) Tevap [oC] (2) DTsuper [oC] (3) DTppevap [oC] (4) DTppcond [oC] (5) nth [-] (6) nex [-] (7) wnet [kJ/kg] (8) mwf [kg/s] (9) nthchp [-] (10) nelchp [-] (11) nchp [-] (12) PHR [-] (13) PESR [-] (14) Toout [oC] (15) mo [kg/s] (16) Twoout [oC] (17) mw [kg/s] (18) Aevap [m^2] (19) Acond [m^2]
     227.881346         6.390844         21.097316          5.927053    0.183182    0.871473    106815.328762       0.520108       0.775977        0.156620      0.932598     0.201836      0.251947       90.943453       0.660987        63.128907       1.374341         2.673516         1.218769
```

Removing the size ratio command slightly alters the dimensions. The problem however persists. Terminal wxt is a disaster, while with terminal qt the result is similar.

I am using 5.4 Patchlevel 3 on Windows 10 64-bit.
Thank you in advance.

The issue was resolved by following the suggestions of both theozh and Ethan. The terminal was changed to qt, the title and labels were offset and the margins were defined using the set margins command. For some reason set tmargin/bmargin/lmargin/rmargin did not work.

Comment: I don't have your data, so I cannot reproduce your graph. What happens if you remove the line `set size ratio -1`?

Comment: Your data is still incomplete. Anyway. If I am using `term windows` my gnuplot crashes. I don't know why and whether it is a problem with my gnuplot 5.4.1 or spiderplot or windows terminal, etc. Have you tried `term wxt` or `term qt`, with this it seems to work for me without huge empty space on the sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to get more space around the plot is `set margins` with specific values adjusted to taste. I can't exactly reproduce your plot, but the biggest issue I have is positioning the key so that it doesn't overlap with the plot content.  I modified your script by adding

```
 set margins 4,4,4,4
 set key at graph 0.75, 1.00 top left
```

to produce the figure below. Obviously the horizontal axis label placement could be improved also.  You could use, e.g.

```
 set paxis 2 label offset 4
```

[image]